# Bloquear formulario si los valores son repetidos

Tags: javascript, html

tengo este formulario donde tengo los campos bl y bl2 donde comparo si los datos son iguales, y si no lo son me envíe una alerta, pero me gustaría que ademas de la alerta no enviara la información.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function comprobarClave(){ 
    bl = document.caso.bl.value 
    bl2 = document.caso.bl2.value 

    if (bl != bl2) 
       alert("Las dos BL Diferentes") 
     
} 
</script>
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" name="caso"><table width="1151" height="155" border="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>BL/BOOKING:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="bl"></label>
          <input type="text" name="bl" id="bl" required="required" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>BL/BOOKING:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="fech">
          <input type="text" name="bl2" id="bl2" required="required" />
        </label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Fecha:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="fech">
          <input type="date" name="fech" id="fech" required="required" />
        </label></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nombre del cliente:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="textfield2" id="nom_cli" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Codigo del cliente:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cod_cli" id="cod_cli" required="required"/></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Origen:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="Destino">
          <input type="text" name="fech2" id="fech2" required="required" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cantidad de items/cont:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="cant"></label>
          <input type="number" name="cant" id="cant" min="1"/>      <label for="textfield2"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Almacenamiento:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="alm"></label>
          <input type="date" name="alm" id="alm" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Retención:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="ret"></label>
          <input type="date" name="ret" id="ret" /></td>
        </tr>
      
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="send"  value="Guardar"  onClick="comprobarClave()" />
      </p>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el atributo `onsubmit` del formulario, colocando una función js que se invocará cuando este sea submiteado al clickear el botón.

La función deberá retornar `true` o `false` dependiendo de si quieres submitear o no el formulario.

```js
function comprobarClave(){ 
  let bl = document.getElementById('bl').value;
  let bl2 = document.getElementById('bl2').value;
  if (bl != bl2){
     alert("Las dos BL Diferentes, no se submiteará el form") 
     return false;
  }else{
      alert("Las dos BL iguales, se submiteará el form") 
      return true;
   }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit = "return comprobarClave();" autocomplete="off" name="caso"><table width="1151" height="155" border="0" cellspacing="0">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>BL/BOOKING:</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><label for="bl"></label>
            <input type="text" name="bl" id="bl" required="required" /></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>BL/BOOKING:</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><label for="fech">
            <input type="text" name="bl2" id="bl2" required="required" />
          </label></td>     
        <tr>
      </table>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="send"  value="Guardar" />
      </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: Gracias @marcos Martinez

Comment: tuve que quitarle el let

Comment: let es parte de EcmaScript6 asi que si en tu entorno no se soporta ese estandar deberias usar var. Ten cuidado como lo habias definido inicialmente (sin ningun keyword adelante) porque tu variable queda en el scope global. Saludos